# Determine if these series converges or diverges. Comparison theorem.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Say I have these series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2k-1)(k^2-1)}{(k+1)(k^2+4)^2}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2k^3 - k^2 - 2k + 1)}{k^5 + 8k^3 + 16k + k^4 + 8k^2 + 16}$$

This compares to $\frac{1}{k^2}$ which converges because it's a p-series with a p greater than 1. The numerators involve subtraction and the denominator involves addition. So the original function converges.

2)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n^4 + 1)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

I'm stuck.

3) $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{n} + 2}$$

It looks like this diverges.

let b = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ which is a p series with r < 1 so it diverges.

Since the original fraction is < b, we don't know anything so we have to use the Limit Comparison test:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{2}{\sqrt{n} + 2} * \frac{\sqrt{n}}{1}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{2 * \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n} + 2}$$

$$2 * \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n} + 2}$$

divide top and bottom by $\sqrt{n}$

$$2 * \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{1}{1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}} = 2$$

so the original series diverges too. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

All of your questions have a general answer. Throughout $k,j\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Given the series

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{an^k+bn^{k-1}+...+c}{dn^j+en^{j-1}+...+f}$$

If $k>j$, the series diverges by the [Divergence Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_of_the_summand) i.e. $$\frac{an^k+bn^{k-1}+...+c}{dn^j+en^{j-1}+...+f}\to\infty\space\space\text{as}\space\space n\to\infty$$

If $j>k$, there are two cases:

$1)$ If $j-k>1$, then the series converges by limit comparison with $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$$
where $\epsilon\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

$2.)$ If $j-k\leq1$, then by comparison, $$\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{an^k+bn^{k-1}+...+c}{dn^j+en^{j-1}+...+f}\space$$

$\forall n\geq1$. Hence $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n}\leq\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{an^k+bn^{k-1}+...+c}{dn^j+en^{j-1}+...+f}\space\space\space\forall n\implies\space\text{the series diverges.}$$

This thinking also works with radicals such as $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}\sim\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$2)$ compare with $\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}$. We know this sum converges.

$3)$ Diverges. Compare with the series whose $n$th term is $\frac{2}{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: sorry, I made a typo in 2

Comment: Ah ok I'll have a look